# How do you change a value on the fly in an ASP.Net MVC WebGrid column?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I have a ASP.Net MVC Webgrid and when the 'SuccessRate' column is less than zero, I need to display 'N/A'.  Do you know how I would do this?  Following is part of my cshtml:

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "grid",
    headerStyle: "head",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("ABC"),
        grid.Column("Units", "units"),
        grid.Column("Min_Req_Res_Points", "mrrp"),
        grid.Column("Min_Req_NRes_Points", "mrnrp"),
        grid.Column("Total_Applications_Available", "avail"),
        grid.Column("Total_Applications_Submitted", "total"),
        grid.Column("Season_Number", "Season"),
        grid.Column("Year"),
        grid.Column(columnName: "SuccessRate",
          format: @<text>@item.Success_Rate</text>)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a testbed I can use to test this example, but is it possible to use the ?: operator?

```
format: @<text>@item.Success_Rate >= 0 item.Success_Rate : "N/A"</text>
```

That, or you can use a view model that supplies the correct string representation of the value.

```
public string Success_Rate_Text
{
    get
    {
        return this.Success_Rate >= 0 ? SuccessRate.ToString : "N/A";
    }        
}
```

Comment: grid.Column(columnName: "Success Rate %", format: item => @item.Success_Rate <   0 ? "N/A" : @item.Success_Rate)

Answer (score 0):

I am not at a computer with a C# compiler at the moment, but you should be able to do an conditional check right within the column definition. Something like this:

```
grid.Column(columnName: "SuccessRate", 
            format: @if(item.Success_Rate < 0) { <text>N/A</text> } 
                     else { item.Success_Rate })
```